# python accumulating while loop keeps repeating what did i do wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, accumulator

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have tried using a break, and tried setting what the variable !=, I am doing this on cengage and it is very finnicky.

```
""" LeftOrRight.py - This program calculates the total number of left-handed and right-handed students in a class. Input: L for left-handed; R for right handed; X to quit. Output: Prints the number of left-handed students and the number of right-handed students."""

rightTotal = 0 # Number of right-handed students. 
leftTotal = 0 # Number of left-handed students.

leftOrRight = input("Enter an L if you are left-handed,a R if you are right-handed or X to quit.") 
while leftOrRight != "X": 
    print (leftOrRight) 
    if leftOrRight == "L": 
        leftTotal = (leftTotal + 1) 
    elif leftOrRight == "R": 
        rightTotal = (rightTotal + 1) 
    else: 
        break

print("Number of left-handed students: " + str(leftTotal)) 
print("Number of right-handed students: " + str(rightTotal))
```

Comment: Erica.. please post your script code in correct format; starting with four whitespaces for each line of code. The code becomes grey in the view pane. Current information doesn't make much sense at all. NOT as a picture!!

Comment: i tried posting it in picture format.

Comment: Picture code is discouraged. People cannot copy/paste and try reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `input()` is outside the `while` loop, so `leftOrRight` never changes, never get to `X` so it will not exit the loop:

```
leftOrRight = None
while leftOrRight != "X":
    leftOrRight = input("Enter an L if you are left-handed,a R if you are right-handed or X to quit.")
    print (leftOrRight)
    if leftOrRight == "L":
        leftTotal = (leftTotal + 1)
    elif leftOrRight == "R":
        rightTotal = (rightTotal + 1)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are not changing the value for leftOrRight after entering the loop so the condition for your while loop is never false I would suggest the following edit:

```
""" LeftOrRight.py - This program calculates the total number of left-handed and right-handed students in a class. Input: L for left-handed; R for right handed; X to quit. Output: Prints the number of left-handed students and the number of right-handed students."""

rightTotal = 0 # Number of right-handed students. 
leftTotal = 0 # Number of left-handed students.

leftOrRight = '' #anything random
while leftOrRight != "X":
    leftOrRight = input("Enter an L if you are left-handed,a R if you are right-handed or X to quit.") 
    print (leftOrRight) 
    if leftOrRight == "L": 
         leftTotal = (leftTotal + 1) 
    elif leftOrRight == "R": 
         rightTotal = (rightTotal + 1) 
    else: 
         break

print("Number of left-handed students: " + str(leftTotal)) 
print("Number of right-handed students: " + str(rightTotal))
```

so that you get a prompt every time the loop is executed and you can click X to exit

Answer (score 0):

Your program just got the character that had the largest id in the ascii table.

And only doing the first string as the `longString = max(n)` wasn't even in the while loop.

also max returns the largest value, so in this case it was just converting the text into an ascii number.

instead you should use `len(string)` which returns the length of the string.

Unlike `max()` which is used like:

`11 == max(11,10,1,2)` as 11 is the largest character.

```
n = (input("Input: ")) #get initial input

longest = 0 #define the varible which we will keep the length of the longest string in
longest_str = "" #define the varible which stores the value of the longest string.

while n: #you don't need that other stuff, while n does the same as while n != ''
    n = str(input("Input: ")) #get input
    length = len(n) #gets the length of the input
    if length > longest: #if the length of our input is larger than the last largest string
        longest = length #set the longest length to current string length
        longest_str = n #set the longest string to current string
#once the user hits enter (typing "") we exit the while loop, and this code runs afterwards.

print("Longest input was", longest_str, "at", longest, "characters long")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there are two specific counts we are accumulating for, and the outlying char is at the end of our input, we can set our while to True to break when we hit a char other that "L" or "R".

```
leftOrRight = ""

# Write your loop here.
while True:
    leftOrRight = input("Enter an L if you are left-handed,a R if you are right-handed or X to     quit.")
    if leftOrRight == "L":
        leftTotal = leftTotal + 1
    elif leftOrRight == "R":
        rightTotal = rightTotal + 1
    else:
        break


# Output number of left or right-handed students.
print("Number of left-handed students: " + str(leftTotal))
print("Number of right-handed students: " + str(rightTotal))
```